# Wait or to know the origin when changing useState() variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have variable such as

```
const [render,setRender] = useState(false);
```

then, I can use call back like this.

```
function clickBtn(){
    setRender(true);
}

useEffect(() =>{
    //do something after render is finished.
},[render]);
```

However I want to change the method by case.

```
function clickBtn(){
    setRender(true);

}
function clickBtn2(){
    setRender(true);
}

useEffect(() =>{
    //I want to know which Btn is clicked and change the method.
       //doSomething1();        
       //doSomething2();

},[render]);
```

or like this

```
function clickBtn(){
    await setRender(true);
    doSomething1();

}
function clickBtn2(){
    await setRender(true);
    //doSomething2();
}

useEffect(() =>{
},[render]);
```

What is possible and how is the best practice for this method?

Comment: Better to handle the side effects in the click handlers themselves (see the docs: [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)). But you can't `await` a `setState` call, the updated values won't be available until the next render cycle, so it very much depends on what `doSomething()` does. Otherwise just set a flag.

Comment: A flag should be the easiest way to do this. An exaggarated hook might look like : https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/affectionate-dew-8tqpft?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A25%2C3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a flag and this can be done using [`ref`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef).

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(0);
  const changeVal1 = () => {
    setBool(!bool);
    ref.current = 1;
  };

  const changeVal2 = () => {
    setBool(!bool);
    ref.current = 2;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current === 1) {
      console.log("1");
    } else if (ref.current === 2) {
      console.log("2");
    }
  }, [bool]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={changeVal1}>XXX</button>
      <button onClick={changeVal2}>YYY</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;=
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/admiring-breeze-qlrq99?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A1%2C1-33%2C20)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very useful to use `useRef` apart from `useState` for my case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider setting a value for `render` that is different per function:

```js
function clickBtn(){
    setRender(1);

}
function clickBtn2(){
    setRender(2);
}

useEffect(() =>{
  if (render === 1) {
    // clickBtn was called.
  else if (render === 2) {
    // clickBtn2 was called.
  }
},[render]);
```

Comment: Thank you it also helpful and solve my problem.